# Is this real wood or veneer, on this table top?

Tags: wood, veneer

I can't tell.  Each plank looks like a near-mirror image of the previous one, which suggest veneer.  But if I look under the table top, the planks seem to appear similar (just unfinished).  Which is it, and how did you tell?

[image: The table]

Comment: When you say veneer, do you mean laminate? Veneer is still real wood, just really thin  Laminate is thin plastic made to look like wood.

Comment: The fact that it's "similar but not identical" suggests veneer cut from a tree, not plastic printed with wood-grain.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely real wood.  What I mean in my question was wehether it was solid wood or veneer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of distinct solid-wood edging strongly suggests veneer

"Bookmatching" (mirrored grain) is not a guarantee of that, as it can be done in solid wood, but the close match of 5 pieces strongly suggests veneer. So it may just be veneered both sides. When solid wood is "multi-part bookmatched" the thickness of the wood (and change of grain in that thickness) means the match on faces not simply "cut and opened" is not close. To have that close of a match suggests thin slices - veneer.

Comment: It turns out you were right.  I forgot that there is an unfinished cable portal in the desktop; I removed the gasket from it and was able to confirm it is veener.  Now my next issue is going to be how to strip and sand this without damaging the veneer.  Cross that bridge later I guess.

Comment: What is the goal? If it's got clear finish now, and you want clear finish, there's no need for strip - just sand, and don't overdo the sanding.

Comment: The goal is repair a lot of sun damage, some water spots, and some scratches.  It is in bad shape.